# Importing UIView to UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on a iPad drawing app.. were i have a UIView class which i imported to UIView Controller. but i am getting errors at `[self.view drawPic:image];`like error: receiver type for uiview instance message does not declare a method with selector 'drawPic'.

Please find my full code below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface signPage : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{ 

    }
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * myImg;

@end



#import "signPage.h"
#import "DrawView.h"

@implementation signPage
@synthesize myImg;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}



- (IBAction)clear {
    [self.view cancelDrawing];
}

- (IBAction)saveDrawing {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *finishedPic = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(finishedPic, self, @selector(exitProg:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self.view drawPic:image];

}   

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}

-(void)exitProg:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your picture has been saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alertView show];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}




@end

@interface DrawView : UIView {

    UIImage *myPic;
    NSMutableArray *myDrawing;
}



@end


#import "DrawView.h"


@implementation DrawView

-(void)drawPic:(UIImage *)thisPic {

    myPic = thisPic;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    float newHeight;
    float newWidth;

    if (!myDrawing) {
        myDrawing = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    }
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (myPic != NULL) {
        float ratio = myPic.size.height/151;
        if (myPic.size.width/302 > ratio) {
            ratio = myPic.size.width/302;
        }

        newHeight = myPic.size.height/ratio;
        newWidth = myPic.size.width/ratio;

        [myPic drawInRect:CGRectMake(109,552,newWidth,newHeight)];
    }
    if ([myDrawing count] > 0) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < [myDrawing count] ; i++) {
            NSArray *thisArray = [myDrawing objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([thisArray count] > 2) {
                float thisX = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                float thisY = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

                CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
                CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, thisX, thisY);

                for (int j = 2; j < [thisArray count] ; j+=2) {
                    thisX = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];
                    thisY = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:j+1] floatValue];

                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, thisX,thisY);
                }
                CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [myDrawing addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4]];

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];
    [[myDrawing lastObject] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

-(void)cancelDrawing {

    [myDrawing removeAllObjects];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}




@end
```

Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `drawPic:` only for your `DrawView` class, which you don't seem to use anywhere in your `UIViewController`. If you want the function to be accessible to every `UIView` class, you should define `DrawPic` as a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html).

Comment: Can you please provide me any example code for this i am new to iPad app dev

Comment: Just follow the link in the last word.

Comment: More on categories [here](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html)

Comment: _you don't seem to use anywhere in your UIViewController_. You should have an `UIView` (if you want to make a category or a `DrawView` if not) as a member variable in your `signPage` class. Don't forget to add it as a subView, too, otherwise it won't be able to intercept touches.

Comment: i add subView and Categorized the methods but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Change your property name from view to mView or something else

```
@class DrawView;
@interface signPage : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{ 

    }
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * myImg;

@property (retain, nonatomic)DrawView * mView;

@end
```

In implementation:

```
@synthesize mView = _mView;
```

Now call:

```
[self.mView drawRect];
```

Comment: nope.. still its not working..u said to change [self.view drawPic:image]; into [self.mView drawPic:image]; right?

Comment: @The Saad : This should be in comment. If you are not sure or if you are giving suggestion.

Comment: @pradeepj. make a property of Drawview named mView. you are trying to call viewcontroller's view. but your method is in draw view

Answer (score 0):

Add an UIView (class type DrawView) in SignPage.xib IBOutlet link it with drawView in .h file

```
@interface signPage : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet    UIView      *drawView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * myImg;

@end
```

Where you need to call in signPage.m access DrawView methods like this:

```
DrawView*dView = (DrawView*)drawView;
[dView drawPic:image];
```

btw: signPage Class should be SignPage (first letter capital)